# My Nuxt application dies when using markdown-it-attrs in IE11 - is there a polyfill?

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js, polyfills

We have a Frontend App developed using Nuxt connecting to a Strapi.io CMS as the backend, which supports Markdown.

Everything works as expected on most browsers, but we have a specific issue with IE11, where, if we include the **markdown-it-attrs** plugin (https://github.com/arve0/markdown-it-attrs) we see arrow function issues across the site. Removing the plugin resolves the issue, but then we lose our attributes on our Markdown text.

Does anyone know if there is a polyfill that would help us with this?

We are currently calling it as follows in nuxt.config.js:

```
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    'nuxt-polyfill',
    '@nuxtjs/markdownit'
  ],
  markdownit: {
    preset: 'default',
    injected: true,
    use: [
      'markdown-it-attrs'
    ]
  },
```